# jquery ui autocomplete number of items retrieved

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using jquery ui autocomplete I need to know the number of items retrieved after calling to the server.

This is my autocomplete

```
    $("#descripcionArticuloEditandoTextBox").autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 3,
        source: '@Url.Action("ObtenerArticulos", "Articulo")',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            articuloModelo = cargarArticulo(ui.item.Id);
            articuloSeleccionado();
        }
    });
```

Where and how can I get the number of items and/or the collection of items?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no built-in way to do this, but you can provide a function to the `source` option and perform your AJAX request manually:

```
$("#descripcionArticuloEditandoTextBox").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ObtenerArticulos", "Articulo")',
            data: request,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                // Do things with data.length here
                response(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                response([]);
            }
        });    
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        articuloModelo = cargarArticulo(ui.item.Id);
        articuloSeleccionado();
    }
});
```

In the `success` callback for the AJAX request, you can do whatever you'd like with `data.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of the *response* event of autocomplete which fires after the search but before the results are shown.

According to the documentation, *ui.content* contains the result and can be modified to change the results that will be shown.

See: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137709/Autocomplete

Comment: That isn't the official documentation. And the `response` event isn't listed in the official docs (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).